# How to update table in react based on drop down selection

Tags: json, reactjs, dynamic

I have a table that has it's data loaded from a json file. I need to find a way to change the value of the {tableDetails.price} based on the selected currency chosen from the dropdown menu. I'm using the react-select node package as i thought it would make it easier. Table looks like this:

```
{TableData.map((tableDetails) => {
                                return <div>
                                    <table className="table-fixed w-full">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td id="tablebody1">{tableDetails.Sample_Postcode}</td>
                                            <td id="tablebody2">{tableDetails.Australia}</td>
                                            <td id="price1">{tableDetails.Price1}</td>
                                            <td>{tableDetails.Price2}</td>
                                            <td>{tableDetails.Price3}</td>
                                            <td>{tableDetails.Price4}</td>
                                            <td>{tableDetails.Price5}</td>
                                            <td>{tableDetails.Price6}</td>
                                            <td>{tableDetails.Price7}</td>
                                            <td>{tableDetails.Price8}</td>
                                            <td>{tableDetails.Price9}</td>
                                            <td>{tableDetails.Price10}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                    
                                
                                
                                </div>
            })}
```

react-select options look like this:

```
const options = [
        { value: 'USD', label: 'USD' },
        { value: 'GBP', label: 'GBP' },
        { value: 'EUR', label: 'EUR' }
      ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated, cheers

Comment: Could you please clarify what your intended output is?
What changes are you expecting to occur when you choose an option in the select?
What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Functional Component you could do something like below

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { useState } from "react";

// Assuming only one element with random price
const TableData = [
  {
    Price1: 100,
    Price2: 230,
    Price3: 500,
    Price4: 780,
    Price5: 101,
    Price6: 567,
    Price7: 4356,
    Price8: 1234,
    Price9: 8790,
    Price10: 3242
  }
];

const options = [
  { value: "USD", label: "USD" },
  { value: "GBP", label: "GBP" },
  { value: "EUR", label: "EUR" }
];

export default function App() {
  // Initialize the state variable with the a currency (USD in this case)
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState(options[0]);

  const getConvertedPrice = (price) => {
    // assuming your prices TableData are in USD
    // I just pulled conversions from google for USD to currency ABC
    const { value } = currency;
    if (value === "USD") {
      return price.toFixed(2);
    }
    if (value === "GBP") {
      return (price * 0.72).toFixed(2);
    }
    if (value === "EUR") {
      return (price * 0.84).toFixed(2);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        className="basic-single"
        isSearchable
        options={options}
        onChange={setCurrency}
        value={currency}
      />
      <h2>My Table with prices</h2>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      {TableData.map((tableDetails) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <table className="table-fixed w-full">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td id="tablebody1">{tableDetails.Sample_Postcode}</td>
                  <td id="tablebody2">{tableDetails.Australia}</td>
                  <td id="price1">{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price1)}</td>
                  <td>{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price2)}</td>
                  <td>{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price3)}</td>
                  <td>{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price4)}</td>
                  <td>{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price5)}</td>
                  <td>{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price6)}</td>
                  <td>{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price7)}</td>
                  <td>{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price8)}</td>
                  <td>{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price9)}</td>
                  <td>{getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price10)}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

For class based component

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { Component } from "react";

const TableData = [
  {
    Price1: 100,
    Price2: 230,
    Price3: 500,
    Price4: 780,
    Price5: 101,
    Price6: 567,
    Price7: 4356,
    Price8: 1234,
    Price9: 8790,
    Price10: 3242
  }
];

const options = [
  { value: "USD", label: "USD" },
  { value: "GBP", label: "GBP" },
  { value: "EUR", label: "EUR" }
];

export default class App extends Component {
  // Initialize the state variable with the a currency (USD in this case)
  state = {
    currency: options[0]
  }

  getConvertedPrice = (price) => {
    // assuming your prices TableData are in USD
    // I just pulled conversions from google for USD to currency ABC
    const { value } = this.state.currency;
    if (value === "USD") {
      return price.toFixed(2);
    }
    if (value === "GBP") {
      return (price * 0.72).toFixed(2);
    }
    if (value === "EUR") {
      return (price * 0.84).toFixed(2);
    }
  };

  handleCurrencyChange = (changedCurrency) => {
    this.setState({currency: changedCurrency})
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          className="basic-single"
          isSearchable
          options={options}
          onChange={this.handleCurrencyChange}
          value={this.state.currency}
        />
        <h2>My Table with prices</h2>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        {TableData.map((tableDetails) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <table className="table-fixed w-full">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td id="tablebody1">{tableDetails.Sample_Postcode}</td>
                    <td id="tablebody2">{tableDetails.Australia}</td>
                    <td id="price1">{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price1)}</td>
                    <td>{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price2)}</td>
                    <td>{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price3)}</td>
                    <td>{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price4)}</td>
                    <td>{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price5)}</td>
                    <td>{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price6)}</td>
                    <td>{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price7)}</td>
                    <td>{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price8)}</td>
                    <td>{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price9)}</td>
                    <td>{this.getConvertedPrice(tableDetails.Price10)}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
    
}
```

Upon state change caused by the Select component, your table will re-render with updated prices.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i needed. Thank you so much.